# Google Play Games Services with Unity3D, can we run/test game within editor?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

i'm trying to build a multiplayer game using GPGS in Unity. Been following this tutorial so far: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/README.md

Here's what i've done so far: 
- Made a game service in my google account
- linked my game to the game service
- added the tester emails
- loaded the project 'Minimal' from the GitHub samples of GPGS for Unity in Unity editor 
- configured my app id and package name
- setup the JAVA_HOME, Path variables as suggested in the github tutorial of GPGS Unity

Now when i click play in the editor and click Authenticate button, i get "authentication failed" message. But when i build the project for android and load the apk in my android device, i am able to authenticate (i can see the Google play signin page and go from there). Does this mean that we cannot develop/test a game inside the unity editor which uses the Google Play Game Services plugin for Unity? or am i missing something important here. I really would like to test my multiplayer game from within the editor or if possible on a real device. I've used Photon Pun in the past for another multiplayer but this time around the requirement is to use GPGS so i'm stuck here. I'm using the free version of Unity4.5.2f1

I'd appreciate any help in this! thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, the PlayGamesServices plugin does not run in the editor. All instructions in the readme require you to build an apk or xcode build.

Source :

> [See Link](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Is there any practical way to test Google Play without having to build the .apk every time?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; but it might make sense to use Unity Cloud Build or some other automated build system to generate easily downloadable APKs for you to speed things along.